# How to modify add type enum table postgres?

Tags: postgresql, enums, ddl

Good day,
I have a table orders and there is a column payment_status type enum but I mysql know how to edit the column but postgresql could not change.

```
ALTER TABLE orders ALTER COLUMN payment_status ALTER TYPE enum_type ADD VALUE 'review';
```

I have to add the review status. but it doesn't work.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALTER"
LINE 1: alter table orders alter column payment_status ALTER TYPE st...
```

the error is this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ```ALTER TYPE orders_payment_status_check ADD VALUE 'review' AFTER 'waiting'; ```--  I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: Works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=05530d6bdd2fc6f3d943778cdf14f1a6

Comment: Do you want to alter the column, the type, or both?

Comment: @Bergi I want to add another enum column

Comment: @UlasoftKoinotUz If you want to add a column to the table, that's `ADD COLUMN` not `ALTER COLUMN`. And it needs to be a separate statement from adding another value to the enum type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `ALTER TABLE`. Use the `ALTER TYPE` command on its own:

```
ALTER TYPE enum_type ADD VALUE 'review';
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE orders ALTER TYPE payment_status ADD VALUE 'review'; ? - I just tried different things but it didn't work

Comment: ```ALTER TYPE payment_status ADD VALUE 'review';``` - I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: ```ERROR:  type "payment_status" does not exist```

Comment: @UlasoftKoinotUz I've added the full statement in my answer. You should write the type name, not the column name.

Comment: @UlasoftKoinotUz `payment_status` is the name of the column, not the name of the enum type. You have to alter the type.